# How to write a makefile for repeated procedure?

Tags: makefile

I have a project that does same analysis on 10 different files. For example I start with `test1.txt`.... `test10.txt`. They are each setup in 10 different folders named as `test1`.... `test10`. I have a python script that runs some test on the files and produce `test1_v1.txt`...`test10_v1.txt`, then another round of analysis using Rscript and produces `test1_v12.txt`...`test10_v2.txt`. Right now i have a `makefile` setup like this:

```
TEST_FOLDER=test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10

test3/%_v1.txt:
    @$(foreach var, $(TEST_FOLDER), python run_test.py -in $(var)/$(var).txt -out $(var)/$(var)_v1.txt;)


test3/%_v1.txt: 
    @$(foreach var, $(TEST_FOLDER), Rscript run_stat.R -in $(var)/$(var)_v1.txt -out $(var)/$(var)_v2.txt;)
```

I know this is really a bad setup, and there is no correct dependencies. It only depends on file in `test3/%_v1.txt`. I have tried using something like:

```
$(TEST_FOLDER)/$(TEST_FOLDER)_v1.txt:$(TEST_FOLDER)/$(TEST_FOLDER).txt
       python run_test.py -in $^ -out $@
```

But, it didn't work. Any suggestion on making the `makefile` work as `makefile` and not shell script would be great.

`make` is great, just need more practice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick about make is you kind of have to work backwards.  Start with what you want to get out at the end.  In this case the `_v2.txt` files.  So those are the things you depend on from `all`:

```
TEST_FOLDER=test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10

all: $(foreach T,$(TEST_FOLDER),$T/$T_v2.txt)
```

Now how do you build a *single* one of those?  Whenever you write a make rule, each rule should ideally run ONE command or one set of commands that generates one output; DO NOT use loops to build multiple of the same kind of output in one rule.  Write that rule next as a pattern rule:

```
%_v2.txt : %_v1.txt
        Rscript run_stat.R -in $< -out $@
```

Now write the rule to create the `_v1.txt` file:

```
%_v1.txt : %.txt
        python run_test.py -in $< -out $@
```

Now you're done!

Comment: thanks this looks great implementing now. One last question on this: whats the difference between $T and $(T), if any?

Comment: ALso, why ` %_v2.txt : %_v1.txt:` doesn't specify folder location? Does `%` looks for the file in all folder? Sorry, about counter questions

Comment: There is no difference: in makefiles `$` introduces a variable.  A variable can either be a single character long, like `$@`, `$<`, or `$T`, or it can be multiple characters long.  If it's >1 character long then it must be enclosed in either parentheses `$(FOO)` or braces `${FOO}`.  Of course you can also write `$(T)`, `$(@)`, etc. if you prefer.  There's no difference in functionality between any of these representations: they're all the same.

Comment: `%` represents a matching string.  The string may contain a `/` so it could represent a file in a directory, or not.  The `all` rule tells make it wants to build a file like `test1/test1_v2.txt`.  So make looks for rules that can be used to build that file.  It matches the pattern `%_v2.txt` so `%` matches `test1/test1`: that's called the _stem_.  Then it uses the same stem to replace `%` in the prerequisite, so `%_v1.txt` expands to `test1/test1_v1.txt`.  Then make tries to build _that_.  And so on.

Comment: The GNU make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html is actually quite readable and explains all this pretty well (IMO).

Comment: Thank you much for explaining this. I have ventured into makefile manual and the readability is definitely getting better.Also, i got it working now but i had to remove `:` from the end though. When i leave the `:` on, i get 
   `*** mixed implicit and static pattern rules.  Stop.`

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part.  Sorry I'll fix it.